# Why Firebase 6.0.2 throws error firebase_app__webpack_imported_module_11__.auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

Have VueJS app with firebase for login, firestore, hosting, functions. Wanted to also add the new performance monitoring, which requires to update to Firebase 6.0.2

Did importings as suggested in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-web).

#### main.ts

```
// Firebase App is always required and must be first
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/performance';
import { config } from "@/helpers/firebaseConfig";

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const perf = firebase.performance()
```

To config added the new appID.

But it started throwing error
*firebase_app__webpack_imported_module_11__.auth is not a function*

also got '.peformance' is not a function

Looks like webpack import is not right, but don't understand whats wrong, because reverted back to 5.11.1 and worked like before.

Any tips?

Comment: _"Did importings as suggested in docs"_  please link to these docs. Is it [these ones](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize)?

Comment: Are you sure you've updated your firebase dependency to `6.0.2`? I only ask as v5 doesn't export multiple symbols, ie you would use `import firebase from 'firebase/app'` (no `*`)

Comment: I installed firebase ```npm install firebase@6.0.2 --save``` and then ```npm update``` package.json says *"firebase": "^6.0.2",*

Comment: Check the `"version"` property in `node_modules/firebase/package.json`. Can't hurt to try the old `rm -r node_modules package-lock.json && npm install` (aka dust off and nuke it from orbit)

Comment: 'nuking' didn't help and the version says *"version": "6.0.2"*

Comment: I just tried updating one of my Vue apps from Firebase v5.5.9 to v6.0.2 and it worked just fine. VSCode did recommend that I convert the import to use the default, ie `import firebase from 'firebase/app'` and that also worked. Are you absolutely sure it's `main.ts` that's triggering the error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/752#issuecomment-469358773) 'brutal' approach solved the problem. Maybe it will save others half day of frustration.

```
npm uninstall --save firebase firebase-admin
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf ~/.npm
npm install
npm install firebase --save
npm install firebase-admin --save
```